# Calculating KJets of SO(2)

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, jet-bundles

I am currently working through definitions and examples of KJets and one-parameter point groups. The text I am working with describes kjets as vector fields defined by:
\begin{equation}
(j_k T_\epsilon)(x,j_k u) := (\tilde{x}, j_k \tilde{x}),\mbox{ whenever }(\tilde{x},\tilde{u}) = T_\epsilon(x,u), \epsilon \in I_{(x,u)}.
\end{equation}
But nowhere is there a concrete definition of $j_k \tilde{x}$. It is only described as a generic element of the kth jet space.

So, in one of the examples the concrete 1-jet of the point transformation group
\begin{equation}
T_\theta(x,u) =\big(x\cos(\theta) -u(x)\sin(\theta),\, x\sin(\theta),\, x\sin(\theta) + u(x)\cos(\theta)\big)
\end{equation}
is given by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&(j_1 T_\theta)(x,u,u_x) =\\
=& \left(x\cos(\theta) -u_x\sin(\theta),\, x\sin(\theta),\, x\sin(\theta) + u\cos(\theta),\, \frac{\sin(\theta) + u_x \cos(\theta)}{\cos(\theta) -u_x \sin(\theta)}\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

How does one calculate the last term of this result? The textbook shows that it can be achieved by direct computation but it nowhere says how to achieve this computation.

Comment: I seem to recall these prolongations involve solving an implicit equation for a transformed function. I don't have access to my notes at the moment but recall I learnt it all from [these notes](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~olver/sm.html) by Peter Olver from his personal website (the section on jets and invariants is what you want).